# Citation of a paper with non-standard characters by Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, accents

I would like to cite a paper by Bibtex. The bib entry is

```
@Article(Zolandek2007,
title = {The {PF030405a} {‘‘Krzeszowice’’} fireball},
author = {P. {\.{Z}}o{\l}\c{a}dek and A. Olech and M. Wi\'{s}niewski and M. Kwinta},
journal = {Earth, Moon, and Planets},
year = {2007},
volume = {100},
number = {3--4},
pages = {215--224},
file =        f
)
```

Bibtex omits the dot between `\` and `{Z}`, so the entry in bbl file looks like this:

```
\bibitem[{\.{Z}o{\l}\c{a}dek et~al(2007)\.{Z}o{\l}\c{a}dek, Olech,
  Wi\'{s}niewski, and Kwinta}]{Zolandek2007}
\{Z}o{\l}\c{a}dek P, Olech A, Wi\'{s}niewski M, Kwinta M (2007) The {PF030405a}
  {‘‘Krzeszowice’’} fireball. Earth, Moon, and Planets 100(3--4):215--224
```

LaTeX then announces error Extra }. If I finish translation in spite of it, the result

> {Zołądek P, Olech A, Wiśniewski M, Kwinta M (2007) The PF030405a
>   Krzes- zowice fireball. Earth, Moon, and Planets 100(3–4):215–224

begins with a wrong brace, the dot above Z is missing and also quotation marks around word Krzeszowice are missing. Does anybody have any advice, how to cite papers with so complicated names?

---

I have read the answers to the question "How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?" I have tried all the characters proposed there:

```
{\"a}{\^e}{\`i}{\.I}{\o}{\'u}{\aa}{\c c}{\u g}{\l}{\~n}{\H o}{\v r}{\ss}.
```

Everything works except `{\.I}`. After Bibtex, the dot is off and LaTeX does not know the order `\I`.

I use these documentclass and packages:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc}
```

The `natbib` package could theoretically influence it, but it works by the same way both with and without `natbib`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You must input the surname as `{\.Z}o{\l}{\c a}dek`, or, better still, as `{\.Z}o{\l}{\k a}dek` -- you want an "ogonek", not a "cedilla", under "a", right? If you want to typeset the ogonek accent, be sure to load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`.

Comment: To typeset the double quotation marks around `Krzeszowice`, be sure *not* to use `‘‘` and `’’` (aka "smart" quotes) unless you use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX; even then, you will probably also have to load the `fontspec` package and use a suitable font. Just use double-backquotes and double-apostophes, as is uniformly recommended in just about every introduction to TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: I get the dot over I with `\.I`; a Polish author named Żołądek should be input as `{\.Z}o{\l}{\k{a}}dek` with the correct ogonek. You need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`; the quotes can be input as `“` and `”` (not `‘‘` and `’’`), but for those you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (if your document is UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the the bibtex style jss.bst which has a function (`remove.dots`) that removes dots in the input. Since the dot was removed the other suggested solution in the comments to the original post did not work, but I found another solution which is to encode the backslash and the dot using ASCII hexadecimal codes using TeX's `^^` substitution mechanism. The backslash is `^^5c` and the dot is `^^2e`, so your bibtex entry would look like this:

```
@Article(Zolandek2007,
title = {The {PF030405a} {``Krzeszowice''} fireball},
author = {P. {^^5c^^2eZ}o{\l}\c{a}dek and A. Olech and M. Wi\'{s}niewski and M. Kwinta},
journal = {Earth, Moon, and Planets},
year = {2007},
volume = {100},
number = {3--4},
pages = {215--224},
file =        f
)
```